# ImageCapture API throwing Platform Error on takePhoto()

Tags: javascript, navigator, image-capture, mediastream

I'm attempting to use the [ImageCapture API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageCapture/ImageCapture) to capture a snapshot using a 4k [Logitech Brio Stream](https://www.logitech.com/en-gb/product/brio-stream-4k-hd-webcam?crid=34) webcam.

All works well on my Mac's built in camera, or using the default video constraints with the web cam, though trying to capture in higher res fails with a pretty generic `platform error`. The only references I've found to this come in the source code, [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/6ef18cc67/third_party/WebKit/Source/modules/imagecapture/ImageCapture.cpp#196) and [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/66.0.3359.158/third_party/WebKit/Source/modules/imagecapture/ImageCapture.cpp#619).

These links suggest either `capabilities.is_null()` or `photo_state.is_null()` respectively, though I've been unable to find what could potentially cause either of these.

Here's my (slightly trimmed down) implementation:

```
// N.B. self is scoped within the code file, and works as it should

const videoConstraints = {
  video: {
    width: { min: 1280, ideal: 3840, max: 3840 },
    height: { min: 720, ideal: 2160, max: 2160 }
  }
}

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(videoConstraints)         
  .then(function(stream) {
    self.imageCapture = new ImageCapture(stream.getVideoTracks()[0]);
  })


self.imageCapture.takePhoto()
  .then(function(blob) { self.doSomethingWithThe(blob); }) // never gets here because...
  .catch(function(e) { console.log(e); }); // here the error is thrown
```

This works with the built in cam, while switching the video constraints to `{ video: true }` gets this working with the webcam, albeit with a lower res 720 x 1280 resolution (the minimum specified). No custom higher resolutions work for this.

Using Chrome as the browser for this.

Does anyone know how to get `takePhoto()` to work to capture a 4k image?

I've found very little describing issues with the API, so any suggestions or help welcome. Let me know if there are any details missing from the question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure the camera supports the resolutions you've specified.

Comment: Thanks @PedroLobito - it should do, bought for purpose :) It's the [Brio Stream](https://www.logitech.com/en-gb/product/brio-stream-4k-hd-webcam?crid=34). I should have specified, but _no_ options other than the default work to take an image, which hasn't been an issue for the built in cam.

Comment: Have you tried it with ff or opera? Same problem? Just to rule out a chrome issue. Are your graphic card drivers up to date? I cannot find any mac driver to download on [brio-stream/downloads](https://support.logitech.com/en_gb/product/brio-stream/downloads). No drivers needed for Mac?

Comment: Driver is up to date, came with a link to get this up to speed. ImageCapture [isn't available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageCapture#Browser_compatibility) in Firefox yet, though good idea to try Opera. To be honest, at this point we're considering switching back to previous tried and tested approaches to grab this. Seems ImageCapture struggles with the higher resolution. At least in Chrome, their own task manager shows `Utility: Video Capture Service` using ~85% CPU before throwing (or sometimes now) the above error. Appreciate the ideas though @PedroLobito, thanks :)